# Detecting whether any socket is connected with any url in system in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I want to detect whether socket connection with a particular ip address is already established in the system. In Linux there are 4 desktops so if tcp socket connection is already established in 2nd desktop and I want to re-establish in third desktop or if I want to re-establish another connection using another user with the same ip address then I should receive an error message.

How can I get this functionality through my java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run [`netstat -a`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) and parse the output.

Comment: Some versions of Windows have a `netstat` command. I'm sure there is something equivalent on Mac OS.